# I cannot add my website URL when add website platform in facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add website platform in facebook, but when i input my website url, facebook send me error message like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhBXE.jpg)

Is there any clue for me ?
Thank you before

Comment: try to post the url on facebook. if it does not work, there should be a link where you can apply.

Comment: Okay i'll try it, thank you for your response